# СУБД Oracle 11g 2 на Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, сервер, oracle

**СУБД Oracle 11g 2 на Windows Server 2008.
Как правильно shut dawn базу и потом рестарт Windows Server 2008, или база работает и перезагружаем   Windows Server 2008 ?**

Comment: думаю можете спокойно систему перегружать, oracle сам разберется

Comment: При штатной перезагрузке ОС корректно погасит все с ервисы, включая Оракл. А тот корректно завершит все свои процессы. Так что не парься, ребутай. Только не делай принудительной перезагрузки.